# Can function operator be aliased?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way how to alias `function` operator without too much overhead like eval? I'd like to write

```
fn test() { ... }
```

instead of

```
function test() { ... }
```

to strip some bytes in minified code. Just curious.

Comment: Nope.  `function` must be spelled out.

Comment: Why? It's already being gzipped, right? So it'll compress down to essentially nothing anyway. Waste of optimization.

Comment: @DaveNewton: Couldn't you say the same thing about unminified javascript?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yep, that's why minification is overrated.

Comment: @DaveNewton Google+ uses a CSS minifier that minifies all the class names, just to reduce uncompressed size of html/css, so size does matter if you serve a lot of requests.

Comment: hmmm could you write a function to define a function? You might be able to get a call like ... `fn('MyFunc', {/*...*/})`

Comment: @Basic: But you'd still need the `function` keyword.  Unless you did something like `var fn = Function;`, and `test = new fn('a', 'return a+1');`, but I *highly* suggest against that.

Comment: @Basic That'll make every function call cost two calls, which is going to hurt performance.

Comment: @Basic You can't pass block of code. It is not an object.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Completely agree, it's awful - I was merely musing, not proposing

Comment: @Basic: well, there is a Function object, but with overhead: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function

Comment: @freakish True enough

Comment: @MortenMertner Class names are not as uniform across CSS files as the word "function" is in JavaScript. The word `"function "` will get an entry in the table, and if used enough, be reduced to a byte or two anyway. Pointless.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yep, hence no reason to differentiate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way to alias function operator without too much overhead?

Nope.

Unless of course you're using ECMAScript 6 which supposedly will contain what's called ["fat arrow" syntax](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2012/04/09/javascript-fat-city/):

```
var test = (arg1, arg2) => arg1 + arg2;
```

Until then, you're stuck constantly declaring:

```
var test = function (arg1, arg2) { return arg1 + arg2 };
```

or

```
function test(arg1, arg2) {
    return arg1 + arg2;
}
```

Comment: Available today if you're using TypeScript :)

Comment: @MortenMertner: But that compiles into JavaScript, and now we're back where we started.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Yes, of course. Doesn't help the poster right now, but would allow him to write his code now in a way that will take up less space in the future (once it becomes feasible to target ES6 directly).

Comment: @JanTuroň: [Fat arrows in haskell](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Keywords#.3D.3E) do a completely different thing - JS fat arrows are just a lambda operator

Answer (score 2):

As Dave pointed out, it's best to write proper script and let gzip do its job.

But, if you're not afraid of `eval()` and being looked down on by your peers, but you could build a preprocessor to customize the language a bit -- one function of which can be enabling `=>` declarations.

**In some external file or hidden tag that needs pre-processing:**

```
f=(x,y)=>{return x+y;}
```

**In your preprocessor somewhere:**

```
var s = loadCodeToPreprocess(whatever);
s = s.replace(/(\([^()]*\))=>/g, "function$1");
eval(s);
```

But again, it's usually best to just write JavaScript per the standard and let gzip do its job.